# VBA Dlookup not selecting items from table where certain dates are selected from drop down

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm creating a database using MS Access, that allows a user to select a person and a week and view the shifts that person is going to do.

Here's my problem, I've got the code working using a DLookup to search for the staff member using the pid, and searching for a particular day as follows:

```
'Look up shifts
If IsNull(DLookup("Monday", "tblShifts", "[SPID]= " & SPID)) Then
    MsgBox "Sorry missing shifts", vbCritical, "Error"
Else
    selectedDate = Form_frmMain.cboWeekCommencing.Value
    'MsgBox selectedDate 'shows selected date
    MonShift = DLookup("Monday", "tblShifts", "[SPID]= " & SPID & " AND [WeekBegin]= #" & selectedDate & "#")
    TueShift = DLookup("Tuesday", "tblShifts", "[SPID]= " & SPID & " AND [WeekBegin]= #" & selectedDate & "#")
    WedShift = DLookup("Wednesday", "tblShifts", "[SPID]= " & SPID & " AND [WeekBegin]= #" & selectedDate & "#")
    ThurShift = DLookup("Thursday", "tblShifts", "[SPID]= " & SPID & " AND [WeekBegin]= #" & selectedDate & "#")
    FriShift = DLookup("Friday", "tblShifts", "[SPID]= " & SPID & " AND [WeekBegin]= #" & selectedDate & "#")
    SatShift = DLookup("Saturday", "tblShifts", "[SPID]= " & SPID & " AND [WeekBegin]= #" & selectedDate & "#")
End If
```

Image of form being used in the database:
[image: Image of form being used in the database]

Selection of table used in DLookup:
[image: Selection of table used in DLookup]

From the above image, the date drop-down is populated from the following code on the form load:

```
thisWeek = Date - Weekday(Date, vbMonday) + 1
nextWeek = Date - Weekday(Date, vbMonday) + 8
weekAfter = Date - Weekday(Date, vbMonday) + 15

cboWeekCommencing.AddItem (thisWeek)
cboWeekCommencing.AddItem (nextWeek)
cboWeekCommencing.AddItem (weekAfter)
```

These each relate to week commencing `22/05/2017`, `29/05/2017`, `05/06/2017`. When either the list box or drop-down box are changed the top function is called to populate the shifts, however when I select the weeks of either `22/05/2017` and `29/05/2017` it works fine, but when `05/06/2017` is selected the DLookup returns NULL values.

A few things I've tried are changing the weeks to the later weeks, again it works fine if the date is set to `19/06/2017`, or `26/06/2017` but again doesn't work when the `12/06/2017` is used as the date.

Everything works fine when just the staff ID is used.

Does anyone have any idea why this might happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because Access is interpreting your dates wrong. Dates in Access SQL (and thus DLookUp) should be US format. Since 22/05/2017 in US would be the 22th month, and that doesn't exist, Access guesses that is European date format. But it should always be US format, so 05/06/2017 will be interpreted as the 6th of May (see [Allen Browne's documentation](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html)).

So change this:

```
selectedDate = Form_frmMain.cboWeekCommencing.Value
```

to this:

```
selectedDate = Format$(Form_frmMain.cboWeekCommencing.Value, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")
```

Assuming that `cboWeekCommencing` is Date/Time type.

Comment: Yes the cboWeekCommencing is Date/Time.I understand what your saying however in the select query sure the search in the table would as the issue i get is from the 05/06/2017.  Yes I'm in the UK so formatted dates as dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're saying. In SELECT queries, if you're passing other fields, behaviour is different. Any time you're using a DLOOKUP you will need to format your date #MM/DD/YYYY#. If you do that, do you still have the problem?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say in the DLookup not SELECT. It's now throwing a type mismatch error, thats after ive formatted the date the way you suggest is that becuase ill need to update the table to have the dates in the #MM/DD/YYY# format?

Comment: Nope, that probably just means that your cboWeekCommencing is not Date type but a string containing a date. You can use CDate to cast it to a date if your locale is set up properly: `selectedDate = Format(CDate(Form_frmMain.cboWeekCommencing.Value), "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")`

Comment: Ok, so ive updated as you've said, I have my decleration of the variable 'Dim selectedDate as Date' which is the same for the variables 'thisWeek, nextWeek', do you set the Date/Time in the properties of the combobox?

Comment: The selectedDate should be a `String`, or you should use the format function later when passing the date into the DLookUp. the cboWeekCommencing needs to be a `Date`, and `CDate` converts it to a date using your locale setting. You don't have to change anything in the form.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been struggling with that for a good hour or so, we have a success. It's now working as intended.

Answer (score 1):

When you have written #XX/YY/ZZZZ# expression in the MS Access SQL query. MS Access tries to recognize a date. At first, MS Access try to recognize a date in the #MM/DD/YYYY# format. And only at unsuccessful attempt it try to recognize a date in the #DD/MM/YYYY# format.

In your example 19/06/2017 is recognized as 19 June 2017, but 05/06/2017 is recognized as 06 May 2017.

I recommend that you use the #MM/DD/YYYY# format every time in the MS Access SQL query.